# Active IO paths vs. number of disks in an oracle ASM disk-group

Tags: oracle, storage

In the [Oracle ASM Administrator's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OSTMG/GUID-18D7AFB2-F417-4E1F-B3B0-02585E385818.htm#OSTMG02550), there is the following recommendation:

> The number of LUNs (Oracle ASM disks) for each disk group should be at
>   least equal to four times the number of active I/O paths. For example,
>   if a disk group has two active I/O paths, then minimum of eight LUNs
>   should be used.

Why and what's the rationale behind this? How the performance is affected if this recommendation is not followed?